# C# - Start a process in background

Tags: c#, process

How do I start a process in the background ?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Users/users_pc/Desktop/rpc.txt");
```

Comment: What's wrong with that line of code? It works for me just fine - a text file gets opened.

Comment: Read an mp3 how? What are you asking, and what does it have to do with the code you showed us to open a text file?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What you mean by `start a process in background`?

Comment: You mean asynchronously, or inside a form?

Comment: You can pass `ProcessStartInfo` and set `CreateNoWindow = true` or `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand right your question, you would run process without interface.

Try that code

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo ( path , arguments )
           {
                Domain = processConfiguration.Domain ,
                Password = password ,
                UserName = processConfiguration.UserName ,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true ,
                UseShellExecute = false ,
                CreateNoWindow = true
           } ;

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process () ;
                           proc.StartInfo = info ;
                           proc.Start () ;
```

Comment: Thank you ! but what is arguments ?

Comment: arguments is an optional parameter (array) used to pass parameters to your process, exactily as you use a console.